# django tuple has no attribute get

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am trying to restrict the dropdown options according to the user type within the same form
forms.py

```
class EForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('t','s','q')
```

Comment: please share the full error traceback

Comment: @Sumithran please check i have edited

Comment: first of all, remove all the overriding you have done __init__, get_form, and form_valid, then check whether errors shows up, if not add those overrides one by one and let us know in which step the error happen?

Comment: @Sumithran if i add form_valid apart from __init__ and get_form it works fine and the all the dropdown options are getting displayed for both usertypes ,the issue might be with the init and get_form

Comment: The issue is definitely with the init, when you're setting `choices` . That error is telling you django forms widget is expecting a data dictionary, and you're sending a tuple.

Comment: @michjnich how do i resolve it?

Comment: Not sure. Post your model to start with - lets see how you're defining that field.

Comment: This is how my filed looks in the models.py files how can ichange that in init? STATUS_CHOICES = (
     
        ('A','A'),
        ('C','C'),
        ('b','b')
    )

    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

Comment: @michjnich i have posted the field take a look status and the choices field options

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to override the entire field.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

So set one of your options (the most common one) as the default on the form - add this code to your list of fields (i.e. above `Meta`)

```
    status = forms.Select(
        widget=forms.Select(choices=CHOICES_OPTIONS_1),
    )
```

Then override the widget if you need to by passing a new dict - you can replace your current `if .. else` with this bit.

```
    if not self.user.is_usertypeA:
        widgets = {
            'status': Select(choices=CHOICES_OPTIONS_2),
        }
```

I've not tested this, but it should work.

Note the options 1 and 2 are meant to represent the tuples you give in the question - so the first one is `C` and the second one would be `A´ and` B` in your example.

Not entirely convinced `__init__` is the place to do this either, but if it works ...

Comment: i have 4 options i have used one already as default when refer to choice_options_1 what exactly are u referring to in my case

Comment: I just didn't want to type out your different combos, so I put options 1 and 2. I thought it would be clear, sorry. You can replace these with a tuple if you like, or define them earlier.

Comment: should both this come under init ? status and the logic

Comment: can u please reframe the code into one again i am confused with this

Comment: I've indicated where this code should go.

Comment: i am getting compile time errors while writing the way please try to write that again that would be helpful

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: please rewrite the code i am getting confused  as i am gettiing compile time error boss

Comment: I'm sorry, but "please rewrite the code" is not helpful. What errors are you getting?